# After Rest Call, how do I get my results from a sharepoint list to populate an html table

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, html

Below is my code, obviously it isn't going to Run because I have external sources that I am pulling from. My main issue is that I can't get the listItemInfo from onQuerySucc to display in the table in the buildTable function. Does anyone know how I can do that? I have it working when I populate the array itself, but I don't want to do it that way.

After onQuerySucc(data) runs, it displays the list item information it pulled like so:

**Name**: Deacon Landen – **Age**: 34 - **Position**: Jr. Developer - **Office**: Charleston- **Education**: UVA - **Degree**: Law

How can I get that to populate to my table so I do not have to manually populate the employees array?

```
<div> 
   <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for EmployeeInfo"/>&#160;<br/></div> 
<div id="divResults">​​​<br/></div>
<br>
<div> 
   <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" data-dpmaxz-eid="45" value="Click Here for Table View"/>&#160;<br/></div> 
<div id="tblResults">​​​<br/></div>

<script src="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<br>

<script> 
    $(function () {
      $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
      getListData();
      });
    });

    function getListData() {
    var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
      
      $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
          success: onQuerySucc,
          error: onQueryFlop
      });
      
    }
    function onQuerySucc(data) {
    var listItemInfo = "";
      $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
      listItemInfo += '<b>Name:</b> ' + value.Title + ' – <b>Age:</b> ' + value.Age + ' - <b>Position:</b> ' + value.Position + ' - <b>Office:</b> ' + value.Office + ' - <b>Education:</b> ' + value.Education + ' - <b>Degree:</b> ' + value.Degree + '<br/>';
      });
      //something similar for the buildTable function
      $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
      alert('Successfully pulled list items');
    }
    function onQueryFlop() {
      alert('Error! Could not read list items');
    }
    
    $(function () {
      $("#btnSubmit1").on("click", function () {
      buildTable();
      });
    });
    
    function buildTable(data) {
        var employees = new Array();
            employees.push(["Name", "Age", "Position","Office","Education","Degree"]);
            employees.push(["Zach Goforth", "22", "Intern","Stafford","Alabama","General Business"]);
            employees.push(["George Fisher", "23", "Intern","Stafford","Virginia Tech","Engineering"]);
            employees.push(["Deacon Landen", "34", "Jr. Developer","Stafford","UVA","Law"]);
            employees.push(["Leon Brooklyn", "19", "Intern","50 Tech","Richmond","Civil Engineering"]);
            employees.push(["Dederick Dell", "26", "Sr. Developer","50 Tech","Georgia","Electrical Engineering"]);
            employees.push(["Jojo Vincent ", "46", "Chief Financial Officer","Stafford","Ole Miss","Business Admin"]);
            employees.push(["Nelly Jerred", "41", "Program Analyst","50 Tech","Columbia","Computer Science"]);
            employees.push(["Brendan Diaz", "46", "Chief Operating Officer","Stafford","Alabama","MIS"]);
 
            //Create a HTML Table element.
            var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            table.border = "1";
 
            //Get the count of columns.
            var columnCount = employees[0].length;
 
            //Add the header row.
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                headerCell.innerHTML = employees[0][i];
                row.appendChild(headerCell);
            }
 
        //Add the data rows.
        for (var i = 1; i < employees.length; i++) {
            row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = employees[i][j];
            }
        }
 
        var tblResults = document.getElementById("tblResults");
        tblResults.innerHTML = "";
        tblResults.appendChild(table);
        alert('Successfully displayed items in Table Format');
    }

    

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like a JS question. You need to build your employees  `array` in `onQuerySucc` and then call `buildTable` within that function. I may post an answer if really needed.

Comment: @user92012, did the code snippet below work for you ? Please check and feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following demo, just need to loop the items data and generate  and append to the  element:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#btnGetTrainingRequests").click(function(){
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TrainingRequests')/items";
$.ajax({
url: requestUri,
type: "GET",
headers: {
"accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: onSuccess,
error: onError
});
function onSuccess(data) {
var items = data.d.results;
var fullResults = '<table id="tableCars" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><b>Title</b></td>' + '<td><b>Course</b></td>'+ '<td><b>TrainingType</b></td>' +'<td><b>Comments</b></td>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
fullResults += '<tr>';
fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].Title + '</td>';
fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].Course + '</td>';
fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].TrainingType + '</td>';
fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].Comments + '</td>';
fullResults += '</tr>';
}
$('#resultsTable').append(fullResults);
}
function onError(error) {
alert('Error');
}
});
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnGetTrainingRequests" value="Get All Training Requests"/>
<br/><br/>
<table id='tableCars' style="width: 100%;" border="1 px">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="resultsTable" style="width: 100%"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Reference:

[How to bind SharePoint Online list data using HTML and jQuery table using Rest API](https://www.spguides.com/bind-sharepoint-online-list-data-into-html-table-using-jquery-and-rest-api/)